# How can I programmatically manage pf rules on the fly?

Tags: firewall, freebsd

I need to query, modify, add and delete rules. I haven't found any API's for doing this.

The closest I've found is the pfctl tool by using pfctl -s and and pfctl -f to dump the rules, modify the, and readd them. Another solution I've considered is simply regenerating the entire ruleset and track the changes separately.  I need to be careful to drop as few packets as possible.

An API in C would be great; however libraries that do this in ANY language are fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most programmatic PF needs can be solved with either PF tables or rule anchors, or even a combination of both. Only in extreme cases you would ever need to recur to the low level device interface. So the first step is to try to solve your task approaching these solutions in order, only go to the next if the previous one did not work:

1. PF tables
2. Rule anchors
3. Low level device interface

The first two options are extensively explained in the [pf.conf](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pf.conf&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+11.2-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html) man page. Once you have your rules, tables, and anchors in place you can modify them with [pfctl](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pfctl&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+11.2-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html). You should be able to achieve 99% of the tasks you'll ever need to be performed by PF with these first two features.

Now, if you really need to access the low level interface, you need to access the `/dev/pf` special device. Once open, you can call `ioctl()` on it to send commands to PF. Sadly, there's no detailed documentation about how to use this interface, it is mostly, but not completely, explained in the [PF device](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pf&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+11.2-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html) man page. I say "mostly" because the part of the documentation that specifically refers to adding and deleting rules is a bit vague. However is a must read to start understanding how it works. Then, you need to check the header file where the structs that you need to use are declared: `net/pfvar.h`. Finally, I would recommend to take a look at a piece of code using the interface for reference. `ftp-proxy` code is clear and simple enough, you can find it [here](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/contrib/pf/ftp-proxy/filter.c).

I would like to emphasize once again that this should be your last option, please check and think (and rethink) your rules carefully before trying to go the low level way. And even if you do, use an anchor to isolate your programmaticaly inserted rules in order to minimize the impact of bad or insecure rules. Also try to minimize the complexity of the rules you add by using anchor filtering parameters (check the [man](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pf.conf&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+11.2-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html#ANCHORS) to learn how to do this). Think that if your program adds the wrong rule (or is tricked (exploited) into it) you could leave your whole network vulnerable.

Finally, I'd like to add a bit of personal experience. I've been working with PF firewalls, mostly on OpenBSD but some on FreeBSD, for over 10 years, in deployments that go from a simple home office firewall, to larger scale (+1500 hosts) with redundancy, load balancing, and automatic failover. In all these years I only had to use the low level interface only once, and because the code base was not only in C but ran in an isolated environment without access to `pfctl`. Rules added by this system are extremely basic, they only add and remove the dynamic parameters that the system gathers (IPs, ports, etc), leaving the bulk of the options to static PF rules written in their standard location at `/etc/pf.conf`. I also used anchors filtering parameters a lot to minimize dynamic rules complexity.

Answer (score 3):

There is no "official" API, but you can take a look at pfctl source code and see how it interfaces with the kernel.

Comment: For the completeness of your answer it would be great to provide a link to source code.

Answer (score 1):

To add/change pf rule you should issue ioctl call against /dev/pf

Take a look at pf/ftp-proxy/filter.c it's simple and clean example of how to do it.

Reference:

http://code.metager.de/source/xref/freebsd/contrib/pf/ftp-proxy/filter.c